# What is the Raspberry Pi power supply connector called?

Tags: power-supply, alternative-power

What is the connector on the Raspberry Pi power supply called?

It looks rather like my Samsung Galaxy S4 cable. Is it the same?

Comment: "What is it called?" I'd call it unreliable, especially when the Pi is sitting in its case :-(

Answer (score 2):

The raspberry pi uses a Micro USB jack. Also see [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/power-supply-confirmed-as-5v-micro-usb/).